# Comparing the execution time between for and while with StopWatch

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to compare the execution time of between the for loop and while loop with the help of StopWatch class. unfortunately I am getting different milliseconds for multiple tests or executions. is there any way to compare or look the execution time in better way. And why I am facing different milliseconds on each execution test. my code is as follows :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var watch1 = new Stopwatch();
            var watch2 = new Stopwatch();
            watch1.Start();
            for (int j=0;j<10;j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(j);
            }
            watch1.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("for loop execution time : "+watch1.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine("---------------");
            int i = 0;
            watch2.Start();
            while(i < 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                i++;
            }
            watch2.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("whle execution time : "+watch2.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: The 10 calls to `Console.WriteLine()` are much more expensive (probably a million times more) than the difference between `for` and `while` loop.  In fact MSIL doesn't have for loops or while loops, the C# compiler transforms both of them into `goto`.  In an optimized build they are both likely to generate the exact same MSIL.

Comment: 10 iterations is by far not enough to measure the speed (assuming no WriteLine). Look at Benchmark.Net

Comment: Don't expect the same amount of _milliseconds_ to pass... there will always be some variability. That's why you'd typically run multiple iterations of your test and take the whole runtime into account and see if they're comparable. Also, you'd need to do meaningful work. Writing to the console is not enough to get something measurable.

Comment: How different are the results each time?  Execution time is likely to vary for a variety of reasons, the system could be busy doing anything at any time.  The execution time being measured here is *so small* that any time taken *at all* is within a reasonable margin of error.  What are you actually trying to accomplish here and why?

Comment: @David I'm new to C#. I am trying to understand how much time does the compiler takes for iterations among for and while. basically I want to calculate the execution time of some set of functions or any statements.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Does the benchmark concept support both standered framework and core ?

Comment: @SrikanthReddy: For what purpose?  If you're trying to measure the number of miliseconds of execution time (which itself is very subjective) then the code appears to do exactly that.  What's the problem?

Comment: Optimize the parts that matter, don't optimize the parts that don't.  An explanation of the phrase "premature optimization is the root of all evil" (and how it is misapplied by some) - https://ubiquity.acm.org/article.cfm?id=1513451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should remove the  Console.WriteLine(i); call from the code since it affects the results.

Secondly, what your trying to do will not show you anything.

The smallest unit of time is the tick, which is equal to 100 nanoseconds (source - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.ticks?view=net-7.0)

Measuring results of code that runs under 100 nanoseconds is meaningless.
Even if the code is executing for more then that. The results will be always different. It depends on the processor and system load. You will not get accurate results.

If you are looking for the Performance Measuring framework you can use BenchmarkDotNet (https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet).

But once again you will not get the accurate results because of 100 nanoseconds limitation and other factors that will affect your code time execution.